# insert via checkbox

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, insert, while-loop

I've created a page to display all users concerning or below a specific manager. If a user has registered, his account will be deactivated until the person concern activate it. i've displayed all the users and a checkbox whether to deactivate or activate. on submiting, the insert command is not working and nothing is being altered in the database. i've got the userid which is hidden but cant apply it.  can you help me please

```
<?php

//get userid from login session

        $memberid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

    //display all users concerning the user(login) is leader
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid in (SELECT userid FROM dept_user WHERE lead_id = '$memberid')");

       //display results in table
        print '<table border=1>';

print '<tr><td>Activate</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Email</td>td>Activate</td>';

print '<form method="GET" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'">';

$count = 0;

  while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $activate = $res['activate'];

 $checked = '';

$user = $res['userid'];

  if ($activate=='1'){

$checked = 'checked';

        }

 print '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$user.'" name="activate[]" '.$checked.'></td>';

 print '<td>'.$res['firstname'].'</td>';

 print '<td>'.$res['lastname'].'</td>';

  print '<td>'.$res['email'].'</td>';

  print '<td>'.$res['activate'].'</td></tr>';

  print '<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$user.'">';

   $count++;

  }

  print '</table>';


print '<br />With selected do:<br />';

print '<select name="useridselect">';

print '<option value="Select">Select</option>';

print '<option value="1">Activate</option>';

print '<option value="0">Desactivate</option>';

print '</select>';

print '<br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">';

print '</form>';

    $useridselect = $_GET['useridselect'];

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

foreach($_GET['activate'] as $value){

print_r($value);

$update=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET activate='$useridselect' WHERE userid='$user'");
        }

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1="UPDATE user SET activate='$useridselect' WHERE userid='$user'";

$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

}

}   else{

echo 'No actions yet performed';

}

?>
```

Comment: Define "is not working". What happens or doesn't happen? What does the query look like?

Comment: Where are the commands for database selection and database connection?

Comment: connection is on another file.. all working except the saving phase. cant handle the useid. i need to set 1 for activate and 0 for deactivate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your update query is getting failed as you are not assigning checkbox value:

```
foreach($_GET['activate'] as $value){

print_r($value);
//Here instead of userid='$user' should be userid='$value'
$update=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET activate='$useridselect' WHERE userid='$value'");
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of the code below.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1="UPDATE user SET activate='$useridselect' WHERE userid='$user'";

$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

}
```

Note: Please make sure that at least one of the checkbox is checked.

Comment: thx dr. its working. suposed i wish to add another option on the combox box to delete the record. is it possible to implement it within??

Answer (score 0):

Change your GET method to a POST method, so the hidden values get POSTED as well to the script. Also, it's easier to seperate your DB logic instead of referring the same script over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same logic for delete too. Use a checkbox array with value of userid